# Why do I get empty string while using split(" ")?

Tags: python

It is quite simple to split a string using .split() since this ignores a plural number of whitespaces and treats them as a single tab of whitespace.
But when using `string_name.split(" ")`, with whitespace the result is somewhat confusing.
Try

```
string = "Hi   Raghav"
string.split(" ")
```

returns a list containing all the words and (n-1) empty strings where n is the number of single whitespaces between the two words.
If the string was to contain a full sentence then the number of empty strings would have been 1 less than the number of single whitespaces between each word.

Why does this happen? Shouldn't there be half as much empty strings as the number of single whitespace because every alternate whitespace will disappear since it's an argument in split

[image]

Comment: Please use code blocks.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split): *If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')` returns `['1', '', '2']`). [...] If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.*

Answer (score 0):

The docs actually have more or less this exact example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']).

So this behavior is intended. As to *why*, we'd have to go on a history lesson, but the cop out answer is "because that's how it's implemented"

Answer (score 0):

The split() function breaks the string by words and it ignore the spaces. If you want to split with any specific character then it should be mentioned as the argument of the split function i-e split(" ") then it consider the space; otherwise the function ignore it.